# why I am getting two different values from system.out.println() and system.exit()?

Tags: java, unix

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e.getMessage()));
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
System.exit(Integer.parseInt(e.getMessage()));
```

when I am runnig the code in unix `system.exit(Integer.parseInt(e.getMessage()))` is giving 254

output:

```
-2  
-2  
254
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operating system's exit codes are unsigned 8-bit integers, so the only valid exit codes are 0..255.

The reason you are getting 254 is because it's the lower 8 bits of `int` -2 treated as an unsigned number.

```
$ for q in -2 -1 0 1 2 253 254 255 256 257 ; do
   perl -e'exit $ARGV[0]' -- $q
   printf '%3d => %3d\n' $q $?
done
 -2 => 254
 -1 => 255
  0 =>   0
  1 =>   1
  2 =>   2
253 => 253
254 => 254
255 => 255
256 =>   0
257 =>   1
```

Comment: if at all i want -2 as a result of system.ext() what should i do?

Comment: -2 cannot be represented by an 8-bit unsigned number. The only valid choices are 0..255.

Answer (score 2):

Since System.exit() needs to take a positive value between 0-255 the `-2` will become `256 - 2 = 254`.

Comment: In practice, that is what typically happens.  In theory, what is happening is not specified by the javadocs ... and could be different on other platforms.

Comment: what should i do in above code if i want -2 to be received as a result of system.exit()

Answer (score 1):

[The exit status code on linux and Unix is 8 bits and unsigned (0-255)](http://steve-parker.org/sh/exitcodes.shtml).

A binary level conversion occurs from `int` to `byte` here (254 is the low level byte of the -2 integer).

Note that this doesn't happen in java (the native `Shutdown.halt0` method receives an int) as this could be different on a different platform.